# I get a zero value after casting a variable in java/processing

Tags: java, casting, processing

I'm trying to declare a variable in Processing (java under the hood)
as following:

> float ww = float(width);

width is a function of processing that returns the value of the width of the screen. In this case is width = 500 and when I execute the code above I get

> ww = 0.00

If you have any idea of what's happening I would appreciate a lot if you point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: Python programmer? have you tired a Java cast `float ww = (float)width;`

Comment: `float(width)` isn't valid Java syntax AFAIK.

Comment: How were you even got to write float(width)? Didnt u got compiler error? :o

Comment: @immibis: processing has its own syntax that gets pre-processed to Java code for compilation.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you're doing? With just this little snippet, the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you didn't post code sample I can see that you are initializing `ww` as global variable. You are getting zero value due to fact that `width` variable will be initialized inside `setup` method. Also it is better initialize `ww` after `size()` is called so you will have required value.

```
float ww;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  ww = float(width);  
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked @Majlik . Thanks a lot, I didnt know that declaring as a global variable could cause this problem but now that I think about it, it makes sense.